# Choose infinite scroll or automatic paging in mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, preferences, infinite-scroll

I'm creating a mobile app that will show images to a user, abit like twitter,facebook,instagram etc. What I've noticed is that they often use infinite scrolling. I've been considering going this road but at the same time I've never really liked infinite scrolling as it feels like i'm not getting anywhere and it makes me kind of exhausted quickly. Therefore I'm considering making a paging variant of infinite scroll that instead. When the user reaches the bottom, he/she automatically gets to a new page and the scroll is at the top again. By getting back to the previous page he/she must just scroll upp and the first page will load and the scroller will start on the bottom of this page.

I know this question could be answered in many various ways and it's alot about personal preference but i still figured i put this out here to see what you guys think about this topic. I've seen some similar question but mostly regarding websites.

**Question:** 
what do you think suits best in mobile devices(infinite or paging to load more content, keep in mind that the user isn't searching for any specific item in the list just simply scrolling) and why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should go for infinite scrolling, as you said user is not looking for something specific, so user would prefer scrolling until he gets bore. Just like FB posts, you scroll down to the end and it then fetches the older posts. But paging should be used just like FB for the better performance.
The idea of new page isn't much nice as when user scrolls upwards he believes that it's just continuous and wouldn't like to take on new page every time he reaches to the top or bottom.

Comment: Thanks alot for your input, I'll be going with the infinite scrolling :)